# Is there ANY way to write an image to the Win32 Console?

Tags: image, console

Is there any way to write an *colorful* image to the Win32 Console? I don't care in which language, but C/C++/C# would be preferred.

Thanks.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937163/drawing-in-a-win32-console-on-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [ASCII art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art)?

Comment: ASCII art (potentially using the 16 console colors) is the only way you can "write images" (approximations thereof) to Win32 console.

Comment: How can I convert any RGB color to the closest of those 16 colors?