# C# Console- Showing an image via a form

Tags: c#

I want to show an image from a console application and I have written code to do so. But when it shows the image, it shows a weird `Form` box. And if I save the image and open it normally, it shows the image.

Code:

```
Bitmap bmpScreenCapture = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenCapture);

g.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
    Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
    0, 0,
    bmpScreenCapture.Size,
    CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

bmpScreenCapture.Save("potato.png", ImageFormat.Png);

Form imageForm = new Form();
//imageForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
imageForm.Controls.Add(new PictureBox() { Image = bmpScreenCapture, Visible = true });
imageForm.Show();
```

Comment: A console mode app is a pretty hostile place for a GUI.  You'll at a minimum have to use ShowDialog().  Trying to get a little pregnant is a bad idea.

Comment: Just don't use a form. Instead look to actually open the image. I think all you need is `Process.Start(filename)` to open it in the default application. (If that's what you wanted to do)

Comment: It's isn't a duplicate because they don't want it in a form they want it literally outputted to the console.

Comment: Yes it is a duplicate! -  If you read __all__ answers you will see that this request is covered there as well!

Comment: @AvidProgrammer specifically, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33652557/80274) is the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are seeing the form border.  You were on the right track with:

```
imageForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
```

However you will need to size the window appropriately.  But you don't really even need a window.  After calling

```
bmpScreenCapture.Save("potato.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

simply do System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Potato.png"); and it will open the image in default program.

Comment: I was testing it but the images are only needed for a short while. I also adjusted the size but it still showed a weird message box. Code used was imageForm.Size = bmpScreenCapture.Size; I also plan to have the image constantly change to make it look as if it's moving hopefully :)

Answer (score 0):

```
        Form imageForm = new Form();
        imageForm.Text = "Screenshot";
        //imageForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        imageForm.Size = bmpScreenCapture.Size;
        imageForm.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom;
        imageForm.BackgroundImage = bmpScreenCapture;
        imageForm.ShowDialog();
```