# How to display an image using C++ right in console window?

Tags: c++, windows

I need to display an image(bmp) in console window using C++ (Windows 10).

Not display by characters, for that I already knew how, but show the image pixel by pixel the way ordinary images appears to be.

And not by launch another application to show the image in another window, but right in the black console window.

I've searched it all over the internet, but didn't seem to find a way to do it without using things like opencv. Is there a way to do it by myself, without opencv?

Comment: You do know that a console window only displays text right? Also there is no way of doing anything like that using only "C++" as the C++ specification doesn't say anything about loading, decoding or displaying of images of any kind.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33538527/display-a-image-in-a-console-application) is a relevant Q&A, albeit in C#, it should give you some hints as the underlying system is of course the same.

Comment: You might also want to specify what platform/OS/GUI you're using, since most solutions will be non-portable.

Comment: Yes, of course there is. 1. open and read the file. 2. draw the pixels. Where are you stuck? Decoding, color quantization, pixel operations, choice of output character? Thresholding an image and showing a 2 tone representation of it is trivial - decoding the image is far more difficult. Try decoding uncompressed BMP, TGA or TIFF images - their formats are all easily available.

Comment: One question: Why?

Comment: the platform is to be put in tag, not title

Comment: @enhzflep stuck at "pixel operation"--how can I print a pixel in console window?

Comment: @beryllium - just pick a character and use that.Since the text-screen has so few adressable points, the pixels will be huge - 100 times the area of a normal one or so. I just use this character:  █ and printf, simple. Consider the following: printf("█ █\n █ █\n"); - a simple 4 square checkerboard.Just draw each scan-line in a loop. Here's something else to think about: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art

Comment: C++ does not have a specific concept of a display. So you need to use some external library. If you want to display something in a terminal (console) then you need to interact with the API of the terminal. So look up the docs for your terminal.

Answer (score 3):

Your hypothesis is wrong: in general a C++ (or C) program might not even be started from some "console window" (e.g. it might be started in "batch mode"). In particular, some C++ implementations may run on computers (such as Linux servers in data centers, which are the majority of the servers on Internet) without any screen (so without any console window). Most [top500](https://www.top500.org/) [supercomputers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercomputer) don't have screens you could access, but HPC software running on them (e.g. [Tripoli-4](http://www.cea.fr/energies/tripoli-4/tripoli-4)) is often coded in C++. And embedded computers (e.g. your [RaspberryPi](https://raspberrypi.org/)) can be programmed in standard C++ (e.g. C++11 or C++14) without any screen or console window (e.g. in 2020 using a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler configured for [cross-compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler))

<sup>(even on Windows, which I don't know and never used, I am sure that there is some way to start programs -by configuring the computer to start some daemons or servers- before any "console window" exist)</sup>

So you should define more precisely what your platform is. In general the answer could be platform and operating system specific. See also [OSDEV](https://osdev.org/) for examples of open source operating systems: [FreeBSD](https://freebsd.org/) is a famous one, and has a [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) compiler capable of compiling your C++ application.

I would strongly recommend using a portable graphical framework like [Qt](http://qt.io/) (in particular, because it makes your code more portable, if you code carefully). Of course you then requires your user to have it, or your distribute your code with Qt included. Consider also using [FLTK](https://fltk.org/) or [FOX](https://fox-toolkit.org/) or [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/) toolkits.

The [C++14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14) standard (and C++11 and earlier versions) does not know about images or console windows, so (in general, without mentioning any platform or operating system) your question is meaningless.

**Study also for inspiration the source code of existing open source programs or libraries coded in C++** (on [github](https://github.com/) or [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/)), such as the [fish](https://fishshell.com/) shell,  [KDE](https://kde.org/), [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) (and they both should be useful to you), [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/), etc etc....

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that without using a library.

One way of doing it would be to make your own console window that lets you do that.

I'm not sure if your OS lets you manipulate the console window's pixels.

Answer (score 1):

A console application can display only text, so you can't draw anything there directly. For draw you need create windows application (in C++, Win32, MFC. or all other language).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to display an image in the console using the SetPixel function. You will need to download the [EasyBMP](http://easybmp.sourceforge.net) library and put it in your visual studio project directory.
I used the following code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "EasyBMP.h"

void DrwImage(std::string imagePath, HDC* console);
int main() 
{
  //Get current console handle
  HWND console = GetConsoleWindow();
  //Get a handle to console
  HDC dc = GetDC(console);
  // Call DrwImage. It must be a bitmap image
  DrwImage("mybitmap.bmp",&dc);
  return 0;
}
void DrwImage(std::string imagePath, HDC* console) {

   BMP image;
   image.ReadFromFile(imagePath.c_str());
   //image.SetBitDepth(32);
   for (int x = 0; x < image.TellWidth(); x++)
   {
       for (int y = 0; y < image.TellHeight(); y++)
       {
          int RED = image.GetPixel(x, y).Red;
          int GREEN = image.GetPixel(x, y).Green;
          int BLUE = image.GetPixel(x, y).Blue;

          int ALPHA = image.GetPixel(x, y).Alpha;

          COLORREF COLOUR = RGB(RED, GREEN, BLUE);
          if (ALPHA == 0) {
              SetPixel(*console, x, y, COLOUR);
          }
       }
   }
}
```

I noticed that if you run it in debug mode, it will throw an error but if you run it directly from the command prompt or in a file explorer window it should work fine. I am quite surprised with the result.

[image]
Note that the drawing of the image on the screen is really slow. For displaying images I recommend using a GUI framework like GTK or wxWidgets. GUI frameworks are well optimized for doing such a task.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, simply by looking thru (or reverse engineering) the [caca](http://caca.zoy.org/browser/libcaca/trunk/caca/codec/import.c?rev=4876) code ;-)

See [example use](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/stupid-geek-tricks-watch-movies-in-your-linux-terminal-window/).

Answer (score 0):

I think I just found what I needed.
 The [SetPixel()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/windows/desktop/dd145078(v=vs.85).aspx) function achieves the effect I want.

Though this image is not strictly speaking an "output", but it displayed.

[image]

Comment: Just make a proper window program and bitblt the bitmap instead of drawing one pixel at a time on a temporary HDC.

Comment: `SetPixel` alone doesn't do much, and you didn't post any code to show how you use it. Is the image still displayed if you minimize, then restore, the console window? If not, then this not the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [project](https://github.com/saitoha/libsixel). Here are some examples of showing images in a terminal:
[image: Integrating GNUplot to a terminal]
[image: Integrating ImageMagick to a terminal]