# In a C# console app, how would I create 'images' for playing cards in a blackjack game?

Tags: c#, image, console-application, blackjack

I'm working on a simple C# blackjack console application game for my school and I was given an example to look at. This example somehow draws a picture of the card in the console window and I can't figure out how to replicate this without specifying hundreds of Console.Write's for each of the 52 unique cards.

[in game scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88P7U.png)
This is what it looks like when you're actually playing the game. Quite nice.

[shuffle and show deck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3TBN.png)
There is also an option from the main menu to shuffle and display all 52 cards.

So what is this wizardry? Did they actually spend a TON of time hard-coding how every single unique card prints out? I sure hope not. This is what I'm trying to replicate and I'm at a loss for ideas besides hard-coding. Thanks for your help.

Comment: have a look at [Display an Image in a console application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33652557/2417602)

Comment: You can change the mode of the console (at least under Windows) to have direct access to the buffer, instead of it being line based.

Comment: You need 13 patterns that describe how to show each rank of card. You need some way within the pattern to say "rank symbol" or "suit symbol". Then you write a function where you pass it the suit and rank of the card to show. The patterns are probably encoded as *data*, not *code*.

Comment: The specifics depend a lot on *what you've been taught so far in your curriculum* though, so we're unable to give much more help. Admitting to your tutor/teacher that you're stuck *isn't* a sign of weakness or failure, and they're more likely to be able to "prompt" you based on what they've taught you already.

Comment: What you said before about the 13 patterns helped a LOT. I was able to figure it out from there. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment, I was able to come up with these 2 methods within my card class. Also thanks to vik_78's comment for letting me know that I needed UTF8 encoding to be able to see the card symbols.

```
    public void PrintCard()
    {
        if (_value == 1)
        {
            _printString =
                " V         " +
                "           " +
                "           " +
                "     S     " +
                "           " +
                "           " +
                "         V " ;
            PrintMethod();
        }
        if (_value == 2)
        {
            _printString =
                " V         " +
                "     S     " +
                "           " +
                "           " +
                "           " +
                "     S     " +
                "         V ";
            PrintMethod();
        }
        if (_value == 3)
        {
            _printString =
                " V         " +
                "     S     " +
                "           " +
                "     S     " +
                "           " +
                "     S     " +
                "         V ";
            PrintMethod();
        }
        if (_value == 4)
        {
            _printString =
                " V         " +
                "   S   S   " +
                "           " +
                "           " +
                "           " +
                "   S   S   " +
                "         V ";
            PrintMethod();
        }
        if (_value == 5)
        {
            _printString =
                " V         " +
                "   S   S   " +
                "           " +
                "     S     " +
                "           " +
                "   S   S   " +
                "         V ";
            PrintMethod();
        }
        if (_value == 6)
        {
            _printString =
                " V         " +
                "   S   S   " +
                "           " +
                "   S   S   " +
                "           " +
                "   S   S   " +
                "         V ";
            PrintMethod();
        }
        if (_value == 7)
        {
            _printString =
                " V         " +
                "   S   S   " +
                "     S     " +
                "   S   S   " +
                "           " +
                "   S   S   " +
                "         V ";
            PrintMethod();
        }
        if (_value == 8)
        {
            _printString =
                " V         " +
                "   S   S   " +
                "     S     " +
                "   S   S   " +
                "     S     " +
                "   S   S   " +
                "         V ";
            PrintMethod();
        }
        if (_value == 9)
        {
            _printString =
                " V         " +
                "   S S S   " +
                "           " +
                "   S S S   " +
                "           " +
                "   S S S   " +
                "         V ";
            PrintMethod();
        }
        if (_value == 10 || _value == 11 || _value == 12 || _value == 13)
        {
            _printString =
                " V         " +
                "    S S    " +
                "     S     " +
                "  S S S S  " +
                "     S     " +
                "    S S    " +
                "         V ";
            PrintMethod();
        }
    }
    private void PrintMethod()
    {
        bool hasWrittenFirstNumber = false;

        switch (_suit)
        {
            case "Hearts":
            case "Diamonds":
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                break;
            case "Clubs":
            case "Spades":
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                break;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < _printString.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            if (i % 11 == 0 && i != 0)
            {
                Console.CursorLeft -= 11;
                Console.CursorTop += 1;
            }
            if (_printString[i] == 'S')
            {
                switch (_suit)
                {
                    case "Hearts":
                        Console.Write('♥');
                        break;
                    case "Clubs":
                        Console.Write("♣");
                        break;
                    case "Diamonds":
                        Console.Write("♦");
                        break;
                    case "Spades":
                        Console.Write("♠");
                        break;
                }
                continue;
            }
            else if (_printString[i] == 'V')
            {
                if (_value == 10)
                {
                    if (hasWrittenFirstNumber == false)
                    {
                        Console.Write(10);
                        hasWrittenFirstNumber = true;
                        i++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.CursorLeft--;
                        Console.Write(10);
                    }
                    continue;
                }
                else if (_value == 11)
                {
                    Console.Write("J");
                }
                else if (_value == 12)
                {
                    Console.Write("Q");
                }
                else if (_value == 13)
                {
                    Console.Write("K");
                }
                else if (_value == 1)
                {
                    Console.Write("A");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(_value);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write(_printString[i]);
            }
        }
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    }
```

[vik_78's answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3pvD.png)

[Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPHKb.png)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need images for cards. You already have them. Press from `alt + 3` to `alt + 6` (on numericpad)

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
Console.WriteLine("♥ ♦ ♣ ♠");
```

Comment: Please look at the linked images to see what I'm trying to replicate.

Comment: @Ryan I don't see any images on linked images, only symbols.