# Is there a way to change the font or make cool art stuff (like ASCII)?

Tags: c#

I am making a basic snake game and I wanted to make a cool title screen with a larger font size or maybe print out the word "snake" like ASCII Art.

It is a simple game made in the C# console window.

I have tried a couple of things, but can't get it to work I just keep getting error messages and I don't understand what the problem is.
[image]

Comment: Well, http://programmingisfun.com/command-line-ascii-design/

Comment: BTW you want to look at unicode art (eg., https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1179876/Unicode-Art)

Comment: Just yesterday I saw https://stackoverflow.com/q/33538527/613130

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add '@' at the start of the statement, it should work.

> `string a = @"a\asdas\"`

You can also use backslash

> `string a = "a\\asdas\\"`